# Filter Multiple Values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I am using Python and Pandas. I have a `df` that works similar to this:

```
 +--------+--------+-------+
 |  Col1  |  Col2  | Col3 |
 +--------+--------+-------+
 | Team 1 | High   | Pizza |
 | Team 1 | Medium | Sauce |
 | Team 1 | Low    | Crust |
 +--------+--------+-------+
```

I would like to filter the `df` so that I only see High or Medium from `Col2`.

This is what I have tried with no luck

```
 df = df.loc[df['Col2'] == 'High' | (df['Col2'] == 'Medium')]
```

This is the error I am getting

```
 cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Any ideas how to make this work and what that error means?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are missing a pair of parentheses to get comparable items on both sides of the `|` operator - which has higher precedence than `==` [(see docs)](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

```
df = df.loc[(df['Col 2'] == 'High') | (df['Col2'] == 'Medium')]
```

Answer (score 98):

This works as well, more pythonic

```
country_list = ['brazil','poland','russia','countrydummy','usa']

filtered_df = df[df['Country Name'].isin(country_list)]
print(filtered_df )
```

Comment: this solution is better because you can use dynamic length of `country_list`

Comment: Thank you! Here the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) docs for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use ( for Pandas >= 0.13 ) :

```
filtered_df = df.query( '"Country Name" == ["brazil","poland","russia","countrydummy","usa"]' )

print(filtered_df )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that df.query is the best way for this kind of things

df = df.query(["Col2 == ['High','Medium']")

Comment: there's an unclosed bracket here